# Field Maps Symbology

Tags: symbology, arcgis-online, arcgis-field-maps

How do I update the symbology of layers in Field Maps? I have added a drop shadow + transparency effect to the layer, but I am not seeing this change in Field Maps.

Comment: Did you make these changes to symbology on the web map that is feeding into Field Maps?

Comment: Yes, assuming I made the changes to the correct web map. I am picking up where my predecessor left off so its been a challenge to work with apps I haven't made. Is there a way to identify which web map is feeding field maps?

Comment: If you open the Field Maps app, click the 3 dots next to the map and hit View Details. You'll get a little bit of info, including the map name, owner, and modification date. That should tell you if you edited the correct map. You may also want to go to ArcGIS online and open up the Field Maps menu.

Comment: I was able to confirm that I have edited the correct map. I opened up field maps from agol and viewed the app in map viewer. From here I can see the changes, but when I open the app on my ipad via field maps app the changes haven't carried through. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Are you using a cached offline area for that map? If not, have you tried signing out of Field Maps, quitting the app, then re-opening and signing in again? Sometimes that will force it to see changes to content.